# Integrated webcam not working in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, webcam

My integrated webcam has fluctuating relationship with me[like my girlfriend- may be the reason is this fluctuating webcam]. Sometimes it works and sometimes doesnot. It sometimes work in one distro but doesnot in another. However i havenot found a way to make my integrated webcam to work in ubuntu 16.04 of my inspiron 3421. It used to work well in manjaro. In ubuntu its not working with cheese, guvcview, vlc capture, skype, viber.

```
--> lsb_release -a && uname -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
Linux android 4.4.0-34-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 27 16:06:39 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

> android@android  :21:44:35  /var/log
>   --> lspci 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
>   00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core
>   processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
>   00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset
>   Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
>   00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210
>   Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
>   00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset
>   Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
>   00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset
>   Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
>   00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset
>   Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
>   00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset
>   Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
>   00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset
>   Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev c4)
>   00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset
>   Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
>   00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC
>   Controller (rev 04)
>   00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family
>   6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
>   00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family
>   SMBus Controller (rev 04)
>   06:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
>   (rev 01)
>   09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
>   RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 05)
>
> android@android  :21:44:40  /var/log
>
> --> lsmod Module                  Size  Used by uvcvideo               90112  1 videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo videobuf2_memops
>   16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
>   videobuf2_core         36864  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2 v4l2_common
>   16384  1 videobuf2_v4l2 videodev              176128  5
>   uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2 media
>   24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev rfcomm                 69632  16 bnep
>   20480  2 btusb                  45056  0 rtsx_usb_ms            20480 
>   0 memstick               20480  1 rtsx_usb_ms wl
>   6365184  0 btrtl                  16384  1 btusb btbcm
>   16384  1 btusb btintel                16384  1 btusb bluetooth
>   520192  41 bnep,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,rfcomm,btintel intel_rapl
>   20480  0 snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1 x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384
>   0 intel_powerclamp       16384  0 coretemp               16384  0
>   kvm_intel             172032  0 snd_hda_codec_realtek    86016  1
>   snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_intel 
>   36864  3 snd_hda_codec         135168  4
>   snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
>   snd_hda_core           73728  5
>   snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
>   snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec kvm
>   540672  1 kvm_intel snd_pcm               106496  4
>   snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core dell_wmi
>   16384  0 sparse_keymap          16384  1 dell_wmi dell_laptop
>   20480  0 dcdbas                 16384  1 dell_laptop dell_smm_hwmon
>   16384  0 input_leds             16384  0 snd_seq_midi           16384 
>   0 snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi irqbypass
>   16384  1 kvm crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0 crc32_pclmul
>   16384  0 aesni_intel           167936  0 aes_x86_64             20480 
>   1 aesni_intel lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel cfg80211
>   565248  1 wl gf128mul               16384  1 lrw glue_helper
>   16384  1 aesni_intel ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
>   cryptd                 20480  2 aesni_intel,ablk_helper snd_rawmidi
>   32768  1 snd_seq_midi snd_seq                69632  2
>   snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi snd_seq_device         16384  3
>   snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi snd_timer              32768  2
>   snd_pcm,snd_seq joydev                 20480  0 serio_raw
>   16384  0 snd                    81920  17
>   snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
>   mei_me                 36864  0 mei                    98304  1 mei_me
>   shpchp                 36864  0 soundcore              16384  1 snd
>   lpc_ich                24576  0 mac_hid                16384  0
>   nf_log_ipv6            16384  5 xt_hl                  16384  22
>   ip6t_rt                16384  3 nf_conntrack_ipv6      20480  8
>   nf_defrag_ipv6         36864  1 nf_conntrack_ipv6 binfmt_misc
>   20480  1 ip6t_REJECT            16384  3 nf_reject_ipv6         16384 
>   1 ip6t_REJECT nf_log_ipv4            16384  5 nf_log_common
>   16384  2 nf_log_ipv4,nf_log_ipv6 xt_LOG                 16384  10
>   xt_multiport           16384  4 xt_limit               16384  13
>   xt_tcpudp              16384  18 xt_addrtype            16384  4
>   nf_conntrack_ipv4      16384  8 nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1
>   nf_conntrack_ipv4 xt_conntrack           16384  16 ipt_REJECT
>   16384  3 nf_reject_ipv4         16384  1 ipt_REJECT ip6table_filter
>   16384  1 ip6_tables             28672  1 ip6table_filter
>   nf_conntrack_netbios_ns    16384  0 nf_conntrack_broadcast    16384  1
>   nf_conntrack_netbios_ns nf_nat_ftp             16384  0 nf_nat
>   24576  1 nf_nat_ftp nf_conntrack_ftp       20480  1 nf_nat_ftp
>   nf_conntrack          106496  8
>   nf_nat_ftp,nf_conntrack_netbios_ns,nf_nat,xt_conntrack,nf_conntrack_broadcast,nf_conntrack_ftp,nf_conntrack_ipv4,nf_conntrack_ipv6
>   iptable_filter         16384  1 parport_pc             32768  0 ppdev 
>   20480  0 ip_tables              24576  1 iptable_filter x_tables
>   36864  14
>   ip6table_filter,xt_hl,ip_tables,xt_tcpudp,xt_limit,xt_conntrack,xt_LOG,xt_multiport,iptable_filter,ip6t_rt,ipt_REJECT,ip6_tables,xt_addrtype,ip6t_REJECT
>   lp                     20480  0 parport                49152  3
>   lp,ppdev,parport_pc autofs4                40960  2 rtsx_usb_sdmmc
>   28672  0 rtsx_usb               24576  2 rtsx_usb_sdmmc,rtsx_usb_ms
>   i915                 1208320  12 i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
>   psmouse               126976  0 drm_kms_helper        147456  1 i915
>   syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper sysfillrect
>   16384  1 drm_kms_helper sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
>   fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper ahci
>   36864  3 r8169                  81920  0 libahci                32768 
>   1 ahci drm                   364544  14 i915,drm_kms_helper mii
>   16384  1 r8169 wmi                    20480  1 dell_wmi video
>   40960  3 i915,dell_wmi,dell_laptop fjes                   28672  0
>
> ---

```
android@android  :21:16:39  ~
--> lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

i tried them

1. Pressing all Fn+ F6-9 and see if it works in cheese/guvcview. No luck
2. sudo chmod 777 /dev/video*
3. lsusb -d 8087:0024 -v | grep -i "Video" *sweet love of uvcdynctrl bug happened to me*

> ```
> android@android  :21:31:44  /var/log
> --> ls -la | grep uvcdynctrl-udev.log
> -rw-r--r--  1 root              root   6945067008 Aug 28 21:31 uvcdynctrl-udev.log
> ```

4. rmmod uvcvideo **then** modprobe uvcvideo . No response
5. to be continued...

If you find any duplicates for me in here please comment me.. I will try.

## updates:

after trying everything i can find on askubuntu and reboot of my drive. i could see my face for around 3 seconds via cheese. hurray. now how to make it longer

error right now

> android@android  :22:04:17  ~
>   --> cheese
>
> (cheese:7751): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed:
>   GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name
>   org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
>
> (cheese:7751): cheese-WARNING **: Could not read from resource.:
>   gstv4l2bufferpool.c(1054): gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_poll ():
>   /GstCameraBin:camerabin/GstWrapperCameraBinSrc:camera_source/GstBin:bin18/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src1:
>   poll error 1: Resource temporarily unavailable (11)
>
> ** (cheese:7751): CRITICAL **: cheese_preferences_dialog_on_source_change: assertion '*tmp2* >
>   ((guint) 0)' failed
>
> (cheese:7751): cheese-CRITICAL **: cheese_camera_device_get_name:
>   assertion 'CHEESE_IS_CAMERA_DEVICE (device)' failed
>
> (cheese:7751): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_new_string: assertion
>   'string != NULL' failed
>
> (cheese:7751): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_schema_key_type_check:
>   assertion 'value != NULL' failed
>
> (cheese:7751): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_type_string: assertion
>   'value != NULL' failed
>
> (cheese:7751): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_set_value: key
>   'camera' in 'org.gnome.Cheese' expects type 's', but a GVariant of
>   type '(null)' was given
>
> ** (cheese:7751): CRITICAL **: cheese_preferences_dialog_setup_resolutions_for_device: assertion
>   'device != NULL' failed